# Getting max value from rows and joining to another table with join

Tags: sql-server

Need help to get query for below output

Table A:

```
ID  Rank AName
1   1    Name1
2   1    Name2
2   2    Name2.1
3   1    Name3
3   2    Name3.2
3   3    Name3.3
```

Table B:

```
ID BName
1  fn1
2  fn2
3  fn3
```

What I want is

```
ID  Rank AName   Bname
1   1    Name1   fn1
2   2    Name2.1 fn2
3   3    Name3.3 fn3
```

Please suggest.
max rank for each id and name from second table.

Answer (score 1):

Try This.

```
;with cte as
(
    select ID, Rank,[AName],ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by ID order by [AName] desc) as RowNumber
    from TableA
)
select c.ID,c.Rank,c.AName,t1.BName from cte c
join TableB t1 on c.id = t1.id
where RowNumber = 1
```

Comment: Definitely look into CTE tables if you haven't before. [Check this link](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766(v=sql.105).aspx). It may seem complicated, but incredibly usefully

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
select
    a.id,
    a.rank,
    a.aname,
    b.bname
from
(
    select
        [ID],
        [Rank],
        [AName],
        row_number() over (partition by id order by rank desc) maxrank
    from TableA
) a
    inner join TableB b
        on a.id = b.id
where a.maxrank = 1
```

Comment: I did not refresh my page and after i posted my answer, i see you already answered it.

Answer (score 0):

Get the max rank for each ID and do a self join to get only the records with maxrank, finally join with TableB.

**Script**

```
SELECT TableB.ID,T1.maxrank,T2.AName,TableB.BName
FROM TableB
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT ID, MAX([Rank]) AS maxrank
    FROM TableA
    GROUP BY ID) AS T1 
      JOIN TableA T2 ON 
        T1.ID=T2.ID and 
        T1.maxrank=T2.[Rank]
ON TableB.ID = T1.ID
```

**Output**

[image]